# Symmetric adding of verts on a Mesh

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I am using X mirror to move vertices, edges and faces on one side of a mesh, and i get the other side automatically adjusted, provided the mesh is symmetric of course.

However, while this works great for existing elements, Blender does not generate the symmetry when i use

- loopcut
- knife
- extrude

Is there a reason for why this has not been added to Blender? Or am i missing an option to enable symmetric addition of verts? btw: Of course i know the mirror modifier, but sometimes its just not feasible to use it.

Comment: The only way I'm aware of apart from the Mirror mod is Symmetrize tool. It is related to the question only in its end result, as it doesn't allow symmetric editing on the fly.